# How to save/upload an image using Tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script that serves as an error logger. Here is my current code.

```
import csv
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Stationdata.ini")  #Locationdata for PD dataframe.

for key, value in config["StationData"].items():
    print(value)
    
    
config.read("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intel/Strata/CfgFiles/Appinfo.ini")

for key, version in config["About"].items():
    print(version)

def log_error(category, error):
    with open("//datagrovera.ra.intel.com/DeviceLabUser/Shared/Device lab Error Logger/error_log.txt", 'a', newline='')as error_log:
        writer = csv.writer(error_log, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now(), error, category, value, version])
        

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('300x200')
    root.title(value)
    category_var = tk.StringVar(root)
    category_var.set('Strata')
    category_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, category_var, 'Strata', 'Prober', 'General')
    category_dropdown.pack(pady=10)

    error_label = tk.Label(root, text='Error:')
    error_label.pack()

    error_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    error_entry.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.X)

    def log_error_callback():
        category = category_var.get()
        error = error_entry.get()
        if not error:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please enter an error message')
            return
        log_error(category, error)
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', f'Error logged for {category} category')

    log_button = tk.Button(root, text='Log Error', command=log_error_callback)
    log_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Users can input both text related to the error, and the category. Using this program I am able to save the user inputs to a CSV. I was hoping to make it so users could also add an image. On the stations we are using there is no way to save a file or image. Users simply do not have access/privileges. We do have the ability to copy paste images using either the windows snipping tool or print screen hotkeys. I was hoping to use the tkinter window to allow users to paste the image so that it could be saved. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is your question about showing images in a tkinter GUI, or saving an image of the tkinter GUI?

Comment: I would like users to be able to upload an image. Right now they can input text, and select a category from the drop down. It would be nice for them to be able to take a screenshot of the errors, and use the window to save them along with the text and category.

Comment: See [ask]. Ask one question for one topic. Also research more, try to implement a prototype, and ask a specific question with [mre] and debugging details if you confront a problem. Did you ever search keywords like "tkinter file dialog"?

Comment: Yes I had searched for those keywords, and others. Mostly all I am getting when I look for how to upload an image is people trying to figure out how to use an image as a background or something. The issue is they wouldn't be able to save these images. They would be images captured using the snipping tool. A copy paste method is my only option, but am not able to find documentation on how to do this. I will update the question to be more clear, thanks!

Comment: Add an image and display it? The question is not clear. You can make the user choose a file from their system and save it on the system?

Comment: I'll have to update the question again... It is likely that a user might want to add an image of an error. However we are running systems that do not allow users to save files. They can use the windows snipping tool to capture an image, or the print screen hotkeys. I would like to be able to paste these captures somehow and save them using the tkinter window.

Comment: If the system does not allow users to save files, then how do you save the screen capture image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` from `Pillow` module can get the capture image from clipboard:

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab

image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
if image:
    # save the image to where you want
    image.save("/path/to/image.png")
```

Comment: That seems to work mostly! I am going to have an issue with it over-writing new images but I was able to create a button that uses the pillow module to save the image. Thank you!